# How can I create installer package in visual studio 2010 with two startup page?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to create my windows application project to installation package(.msi). I have created the package and installed successfully. The problem which I am facing is my project contains two forms in Startup. i.e. "The program.cs file contains two Classes such as Program and Options". Due to this, by checking my project properties, the start up object contains two name such as windows.Program and windows.Options.

When I select windows.Program in Startup object and run my code, the program class has been start up of my application and if I choose windows.Options then my project starts to run with Option class first.

***Note:***When i create a installation package in my project in.msi format, the installation has been done but only one Startup code was run, if I choose Startup object as windows.Program and then create a installer means,the installation package run only windows.program module else I choose windows.Options in my project and create installer then it run only Option page.

I need to create a installation package and after installation done, my start menu needs to show both Program and Options in one folder called project, when I chick "Options" the options has to run in my project, and when I click program then the program part has to run. Please let me know how to create a installation package in this manner. It is very useful to me if I learn the steps.

Comment: Probably you will need to use 2 separate projects. You may only assign one `StartupObject` per project.

Comment: so you basically need to install from one installer two applications and create links for both of them during installation?

Comment: @rudolf_franek: yes, actually windows.Options contains getting the configuration from user. Based on user information, the windows.Program has to run. This is concept.